# how to reference css files after creating different paths using rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my root, I have index.php which references css files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" />
```

I have a rewrite rule that makes my path example.com/products/.....

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ product-detail.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

The issue I have is that the css links are now broken on the products pages because the reference to the css files is incorrect as it should change to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom.css" type="text/css" />
```

I would like to have a header.php file where I can just make changes once if I need to add or remove css references but now I have to have 2 make changes twice. Is there a way around this?

Comment: how about creating a rewrite rule for css files?

Answer (score 0):

you can start the include with the root path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it still isn't working. Not sure if it makes a difference but I am using localhost, not a live server

Comment: Using your suggestion takes me to http://localhost:888/css/style.css which obviously won't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to the head:

```
<base href="//localhost:8888/mysite/" />
```